# Get contact's phone numbers and emails using the Windows Live/OneDrive REST API

Tags: contacts, windows-live, live-sdk, outlook.com, onedrive

Has anyone successfully used the Live SDK (also called OneDrive SDK) to retrieve the email addresses and/or phone numbers of an user's contacts ?

The best I have been able to do is the get profiles for a users contacts but it only includes hashed email addresses and no phone numbers, like this for example :

```
{
  "id": "contact.1e680c06000000000000000000000006",
  "first_name": "James",
  "last_name": "Cameron",
  "name": "James Cameron", 
  "gender": null,
  "is_friend": false, 
  "is_favorite": false,
  "user_id": null, 
  "email_hashes": [ "3972d8781911deba416ecf8e44dcc5f4dae92ab9aac58520bcfa480c31ea38f5", "301e45d554a7978c2a8ef1e662876411dfbca4b89535d2362dff3f6d786366b7" ],
  "updated_time": "2011-07-21T20:31:11+0000"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

All you need to do is add the following scope to your list of scopes you're requesting:

"wl.contacts_emails"

e.g.

```
WL.login({scopes: ["wl.contacts_emails"]});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use hidden scopes, not officially supported but I can confirm they currently work at version 5.6 despite the MSDN forums telling you they don't.

For emails use `wl.contacts_emails`, for phone numbers use `wl.contacts_phone_numbers`.

Answer (score 2):

As per this document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/hh278351

You can have only emails of contacts that are already in your database. This means that Microsoft wants you to calculate hashes for all of your email addresses in your websites database. Than once you do the contact import you compare your hashes with the hashes they gave you in the response and retrieve FROM YOUR DATABASE the emails that had matching hashes:

Here is original text:

> For your website to participate in this scenario, you must create a hash of each email address that belongs to each registered user of your website. Each of these hashes must follow a specific format that the Live Connect APIs recognize. After you have created a hash for each of your registered users' email addresses, you can compare your list of hashes with the list of email-address hashes that Live Connect generates for the visiting user's contacts. Each matching hash represents a registered user of your website who is also one of the visiting user's contacts.

The only way to bypass that as far as I can tall is to do website scraping or to figure out how to trigger automatic contact export and just process the exported file.