# How to retrieve phone number from live account using scope me/contacts?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am working on a windows 8 metro app where I need to read phone numbers of my windows live contacts. The project is in javascript and it uses "WL.API" kind of methods to contact with Live. I am able to retrieve firstname and lastname but not the phone number of a live contact using the scope "me/contacts"...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get contact's phone numbers and emails using the Windows Live/OneDrive REST API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785828/get-contacts-phone-numbers-and-emails-using-the-windows-live-onedrive-rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

Phone number does not appear to be a return value of me/contacts.  See the [Interactive SDK](http://isdk.dev.live.com/ISDK.aspx) and the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826527.aspx#reading).

Comment: does Microsoft.live.services.contacts fit the purpose?? How to use this class in win8 consumer preview??

Comment: Do you have any idea of which scope helps in retrieving phone number??